# Datastore why use key and id?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I had a question regarding why Google App Engine's Datastore uses a key and and ID. Coming from a relational database background I am comparing entities with rows, so why when storing an entity does it require a key (which is a long automatically generated string) and an ID (which can be manually or automatically entered)? This seems like a big waste of space to identify a record. Again I am new to this type of database, so I may be missing something.

Comment: The id is just part of the key which you can have control over if you choose.  Have a read of `https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities` which defines what a key is/does for you

Comment: To clarify, you have to have both then because the key is reliant on the id?

Comment: Yes, for some use cases you may want to explicitly set the id in the key.

Answer (score 1):

Key design is a critical part of efficient Datastore operations. The keys are what are stored in the built-in and custom indexes and when you are querying, you can ask to have only keys returned (in Python: `keys_only=True`). A keys-only query costs a fraction of a regular query, both in $$ and to a lesser extent in time, and has very low deserialization overhead.

So, if you have useful/interesting things stored in your key id's, you can perform keys-only queries and get back lots of useful data in a hurry and very cheaply.

Note that this extends into parent keys and namespaces, which are all part of the key and therefore additional places you can "store" useful data and retrieve all of it with keys-only queries.

It's an important optimization to understand and a big part of our overall design.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the key is built from two pieces of information :

- The entity type (in Objectify, it is the class of the object)
- The id/name of the entity

So, for a given entity type, key and id are quite the same.

If you do not specify the ID yourself, then a random ID is generated and the key is created based on that random id.